# Change color of whole element + override inside elements

Tags: css

I have elements that look like this:

```css
div {
  font-size: 14px;
}

div:hover {
  color: red;
}

label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
}

label:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Text1
  <label>
    Text2
    </label>
</div>
```

what I want to do is whenever you hover on dev I want to change the color of the text - both in dev and in label elements to red.
however the defined color for label (which should exist) override the hover color when the event happens

how can I fix this?

thank you!

Comment: So you mean, when you hover the div, both div and label colours should be red, and when its not hovered, label should be in blue color ?

Comment: if you do not want the `text2` to turn red use `not()` in css when `hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div
{
   font-size:14px;
}
div:hover, div:hover label
{
   color : red;
}
label
{
   font-size:12px;
   color : blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
Text1
<label>
Text2
</label>
</div>
```